# How to invoke another controller's action in different application from a controller which is also in other application?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I have a web service called "news_feed_backend" and an active resource client called "news_feed_frontend", I want to call "news_feed_backend" controller's index action which actually renders the news feed in an xml format at the client(news_feed_frontend broswer), I am just not getting an idea how would I accomplish it. My news_feed_backend controller is below:

```
# Load an RSS feed from the supplied URL. If the feed is not loaded, return nil.

def load_latest_news_feed_for_url(rss_feed_url_to_load)

     to_return = nil

  if rss_feed_url_to_load != nil

   begin

     to_return = RSS::Parser.parse(open(rss_feed_url_to_load).read, false).items[0...5]

rescue

     to_return = nil

   end

 end
 to_return
end

def index

@fd = FeedDetail.new

@url = @fd.get()

@news_feed = load_latest_news_feed_for_url(@url)

render :xml => @news_feed, :content_type => 'application/rss'

end
```

I am trying something like this in my news_feed_frontend's (client) controller:

```
def index

 url_for :controller => 'feed_details', :action => 'index'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

try this - with this method your url will stay on the "news feed" and your output should be your xml from the backend.

```
def index      
      render :template => 'feed_details/index'
end
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Thanks daniel for your kind help.